# Spark NullPointerException inside foreach loop

Tags: scala, foreach, nullpointerexception, apache-spark, rdd

I have RDD and I want to loop over it. I do like this:

```
pointsMap.foreach({ p =>
  val pointsWithCoordinatesWithDistance = pointsMap.leftOuterJoin(xCoordinatesWithDistance)
  pointsWithCoordinatesWithDistance.foreach(println)
  println("---")
})
```

However, NullPointerException is occuring:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.<init>(RDD.scala:125)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.CoGroupedRDD.<init>(CoGroupedRDD.scala:69)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions.cogroup(PairRDDFunctions.scala:651)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions.leftOuterJoin(PairRDDFunctions.scala:483)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions.leftOuterJoin(PairRDDFunctions.scala:555)
...
```

Both `pointsMap` and `xCoordinatesWithDistance` are initialized before foreach and contain elements. Not inside foreach loop `leftOuterJoin` also works. For the full version of my code please see https://github.com/timasjov/spark-learning/blob/master/src/DBSCAN.scala

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use a RDD in a function of some RDD operator. You need to use proper RDD operators when you want to manipulate more than one RDDs together, such as `join`.

Comment: So, I cannot use RDD functions (like join) inside other RDD function (like foreah)? If yes, then how can I rewrite the code?

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "proper RDD operators"?

Comment: You should not use RDDs inside RDD functions. I'm confused about why you need to put `pointsMap.leftOuterJoin(xCoordinatesWithDistance)` inside the `foreach`?

Comment: I am trying to implement DBSCAN clustering algorithm. I have already calculated distances between all points (pointsWithinEps) and then for each point in points I want to see how many neighbors it has (filter xCoordinatesWithDistance). If more than minPointsInCluster, then expand the cluster all loop also all this point neighbors. How can I implement this if not by using foreach loop?

Comment: Could you write the full codes so that I can understand your intent? I only saw `println` in the `foreach` and it confused me.

Comment: Full code is here: https://github.com/timasjov/spark-learning/blob/master/src/DBSCAN.scala So in the for loop for each point I am trying to filter the points are his neighbors.

Comment: I know nothing about `DBSCAN`. But if you really want the `foreach` loop, you can use `pointsMap.collect().foreach`. Make sure you have enough memory to store `pointsMap` in the driver.